# How to install Windows while Linux is already installed? (Dual Boot)

Tags: linux, windows, multi-boot, linux-mint

i've got Linux Mint on my machine and need Windows to be installed.
Is there a way to install Windows without overwriting the bootloader?
Also I couldn't find any guide how to backup/recover the bootloader, since all guides show installing windows first.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

My experience is, No, you will overwrite the bootloader because Windows doesn't play nice in the sandbox.

You will need to install Windows first, then the latest version of Mint, which will allow you to install side-by-side and use Dual-boot.

Word of a 20+ year Linux vet here. You'll find that as you get more into Linux, you will begin to hate having to leave it to run Windows. I have Win7 in a VBox VM and run it about every month, or less. At work. At home, same situation, and I forget to run Windows for more than 3 or 4 months.

Good luck, and Welcome to Super User on StackExchange.

Comment: It's true, I don't like to leave Linux, which I had to often, because the printing driver sucks (wrong scaling). There're also other reasons: I prefer seamless all in one solutions (current version of Thunterbid doesn't support Lightning, which annoys me, Outlook at work is really nice). Another reason is, friends often ask to play games, which I can't run on linux, at least stable. However, I like the learning experience and digging deep into the internals of the os. I hope I will be able to contribute to the linux community some day - this is the real reason why i stick to linux.

Comment: Just remembered I've got multiple hard drives. As far as I know, MBR will be written to 1 hard drive. After the windows installation I can setup the bios to load from the linux hard drive, am I right?

Comment: I'm not sure because I've never installed that way. Typically, however, the MBR on only the primary drive, or at least the one with the Boot flag set, is where the MBR is read from.
As for thunderbird, you may need to search for the new lightning plugin in your distribution's repository. That's where it is now. xdg-xul-lightning on Debian-based systems, I believe.